# bilinear form of positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a positive-definite matrix and $x$,$y$ are non negative vectors, is $f(A)=x^TAy$ positive ?

Comment: what are _non negative_ vectors?

Comment: each element is non-negative

Comment: x=y=0 would give f(A)=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, we have
$$\left\langle \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle = \left\langle \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle=-1.$$